# Show a value from MongoDB into a Datatable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, datatables

I´m working on a NodeJS (express.js), and I need to show a bunch of data (called conteudo) from a MongoDB Model into a Datatable, but it´s not working well.
My intension was: in the route that renders the page, pass the class to the interface, and the content is already in the class object (called turma), to make it listing. For populate the table, create a javascript object at the end of the page (_conteudo).
I´m not able to populate this table with my actual code.

Here is my files:

model.js

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

/**
 * Esquema dos dados de turmas
 */
const TurmaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  instrutor: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  dataInicio: Date,
  dataTermino: Date,
  qtdVagas: Number,
  numero: Number,
  curso: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Curso'
  },
  abas: [String],
  situacao: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: 'Aberta',
    enum: ['Aberta', 'Inscrições encerradas', 'Em andamento', 'Encerrada', 'Cancelada']
  },
  habilitada: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: true
  },
  inscricoes: [{
    aluno: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Usuario',
    },
    situacao: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'Solicitada',
      enum: ['Solicitada', 'Confirmada', 'Rejeitada'],
    },
    dataHoraInscricao: Date,
    aptoParaReceberCertificado: {
      required: true,
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  }],

  conteudo: [{
    tipo: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['TEXTO', 'LINK'],
    },
    visivel: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
    criador: {
      nome: String,
      email: String,
      _idUsuario: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
    dataCriacao: Date,
    dataAtualizacao: Date,
    titulo: String,
    payload: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    tag: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Home'
    }
  }],
  formacaoAlvo: [String],
  textoPersonalizadoEmailInscricao: String,
  textoPersonalizadoEmailAnuncio: String,
}, { timestamps: true });

//exportando o esquema para uso
const Turma = mongoose.model('Turma', TurmaSchema);
module.exports = Turma;
```

route.js

```
router.get('/:_idTurma/conteudos', LogService.registrarRequisicao, AutenticacaoService.autenticarRequisicaoEmSessaoOrganizacaoOuEquipeTecnica, async(req, res) => {
  try {
    let turma = await TurmaService.buscarPorId(req.params._idTurma);
    if (!turma) {
      throw 'Sem Turmas Cadastradas';
    }
    res.render('index', {
    titulo: 'QualiFacti - Conteudos na turma',
    req: {
      conteudo_id: 'turmas/conteudos',
      session: req.session,
      _idTurma: req.params._idTurma,
      plugins: ['DataTables'],
    },
    turma: turma
  });
} catch (e) {
  return res.status(422).json({ mensagem: '' + e });
}
});
```

conteudos.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/turmas/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    },
    success: function(_conteudo) {
      $('#kt_datatable_2').DataTable({
        data: _conteudo.map(c => [
          c._id,
          c.curso.nome,
          c.nome,
        ]),
        columnDefs: [{
          targets: [0,1,2],
          width: 'auto',
          className: 'text-center',
        }],
        columns: [{
          title: 'ID',
          width: '150px',
        },],
        columns: [{
          title: 'Curso',
          width: '150px',
        },],
        columns: [{
          title: 'Título',
          width: '150px',
        },],
        "language": {
          "decimal": "",
          "emptyTable": "Nenhuma inscrição disponível nessa turma.",
          "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
          "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 para 0 de 0 registros",
          "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ total registros)",
          "infoPostFix": "",
          "thousands": ",",
          "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ registros",
          "loadingRecords": "Carregando...",
          "processing": "Processando...",
          "search": "Busca:",
          "zeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
          "paginate": {
            "first": "Primeiro",
            "last": "Último",
            "next": "Próximo",
            "previous": "Anterior"
          },
          "aria": {
            "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
            "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
          }
        },
        mobile: {
          layout: 'compact'
        },
        responsive: true,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

conteudos.ejs

```
<!--begin::DataTable-->
<div class="card card-custom">
  <div class="card-header flex-wrap border-0 pt-6 pb-0">
    <div class="card-title">
      <h3 class="card-label font-weight-bolder">
        Listagem de Conteúdos em Turmas
        <span class="d-block text-muted pt-2 font-size-sm"></span>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body card-custom ">
    <!--begin: Datatable-->
    <table class="table table-separate table-head-custom table-checkable " id="kt_datatable_2">
    </table>
    <!--end: Datatable-->
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const _idTurma = '<%= req._idTurma %>';
  const _conteudo = '<%= JSON.stringify(turma.conteudo.map(c => ({_id: c._id, titulo: c.titulo, tipo: c.tipo, payload: c.payload}))) %>';
</script>
```

Comment: I have not tried to recreate your issue, but looking at your code, the DataTable's columns are missing their `data` options. You have `title` and `width` but no `data`. This would be OK if each row of your source data was itself a JavaScript _array_ - but it isn't - each row is sourced from a JavaScript _object_. Example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) - this is an Ajax source, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Also, you have many `columns` arrays - so only the last one will be used, all the others will be ignored. You should only have one `columns: [ ...]` array. There are examples you can use as a guide - [here is one](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

Comment: @andrewJames Thanks. I see what you think, but, even when I use "data" into columns parameter, I have same problem. I believe that  issue is at "data: _conteudo.map" line, but I was unable to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Understood. Basically you have problems hiding behind problems, I think. My recommendation: Start simple, with a 100% self-contained web page using hard-coded data in a JS variable. That way you will figure out how to set up your DataTable correctly. Then, refactor that solution to include the Ajax piece. For `data: _conteudo.map`, that assumes your `_contuedo` variable contains an array called `map`, since that option tells DataTables where to look for the array containing your source data. DataTables then iterates over each element of the array to build each row in the DataTable.